# Write dataframe to yaml R

Tags: r, yaml

I have a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("bob","joe"),
                 target = c("yellow", "grey"),
                 code1 = c("fly", "walk"),
                 code2 = c("jump", "run"))
```

And I would like to write the information to a yaml file with a specific structure:

```
samples:
        bob:
            target: yellow
            code1: fly
            code2: jump

        joe:
            target: grey
            code1: walk
            code2: run
```

I am having trouble achieving a yaml output with this specific structure.

Comment: Are you using the yaml package? How are you trying currently?

Comment: @be_green Does yaml package offer saving functions?

Comment: I'd think you would just save by connecting to a text file and dumping the content, but as.yaml provides a nice convenience function. The problem here is that he has heirarchical data that isn't represented properly by the data.frame.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A version using no packages except for the `yaml` output:

```
library(yaml)
out <- as.yaml(list(samples=split(replace(df, "name", NULL), df$name)))

# just to show it works: 
cat(out)

#samples:
#  bob:
#    target: yellow
#    code1: fly
#    code2: jump
#  joe:
#    target: grey
#    code1: walk
#    code2: run
```

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else comes across this question & wants a more complete solution, this is how I solved a similar problem in my workflow using the [purrr](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/) package.

Here is my example data:

```r
df <- data.frame(name = c("bob", "bob", "joe", "joe"),
                 target = c("yellow", "red", "yellow", "red"),
                 method = c("fly", "jump", "walk", "run"),
                 after = c("lunch", "breakfast", "dinner", "breakfast"),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)
```

It's similar to that provided by the OP but includes an additional level.

Here is how I constructed the YAML file:

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

nested_lists <- df %>%
  split(f = .$name) %>%
  purrr::map(dplyr::select, -name) %>%
  purrr::map(~ split(.x, f = .x$target)) %>%
  purrr::map_depth(2, dplyr::select, -target) %>%
  list(samples = .)
```

This object `nested_lists` is then amenable to writing to file using `yaml::write_yaml` or printing to screen using `as.yaml`:

```r
> cat(yaml::as.yaml(nested_lists))
samples:
  bob:
    red:
      method: jump
      after: breakfast
    yellow:
      method: fly
      after: lunch
  joe:
    red:
      method: run
      after: breakfast
    yellow:
      method: walk
      after: dinner
```

This is nice approach in that it generalizes well to any number of levels.

For example, if we replace the `purrr::map(...)` calls with `purrr::map_depth(1, ...)` and extend the nested lists to another level, the pattern becomes more clear:

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

nested_lists3 <- df %>%
  split(f = .$name) %>%
  purrr::map_depth(1, dplyr::select, -name) %>%
  purrr::map_depth(1, ~ split(.x, f = .x$target)) %>%
  purrr::map_depth(2, dplyr::select, -target) %>%
  purrr::map_depth(2, ~ split(.x, f = .x$method)) %>%
  purrr::map_depth(3, dplyr::select, -method) %>%
  list(samples = .)

cat(yaml::as.yaml(nested_lists3))
```

Produces:

```r
samples:
  bob:
    red:
      jump:
        after: breakfast
    yellow:
      fly:
        after: lunch
  joe:
    red:
      run:
        after: breakfast
    yellow:
      walk:
        after: dinner
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you are doing this now, but here's my solution, using the yaml and data.table libraries. First we construct the data.table, then construct the nested format you would like, then remove the name column from each element of the list, and then convert it to a yaml object. The `cat` function returns the text without manipulation.

```
library(data.table)
library(yaml)
library(magrittr)

df <- data.table(name = c("bob","joe"),
                 target = c("yellow", "grey"),
                 code1 = c("fly", "walk"),
                 code2 = c("jump", "run")) %>% 
  split(by = "name") %>%
  lapply(function(x) x[,name := NULL] %>% .[]) %>% 
  list(samples = .) %>% 
  as.yaml

> cat(df)
samples:
  bob:
    target: yellow
    code1: fly
    code2: jump
  joe:
    target: grey
    code1: walk
    code2: run
```

You can then write out the file with the `write` function.

```
write(df, "C:/filepath/file.txt")
```

Comment: Why are you loading data.table, to recreate the `df` that's already provided, just to do one NULL assignment? And you haven't loaded magrittr or dplyr to use the `%>%` pipe.

Comment: Two formatting issues: the `name` should be indented 2 tabs, and each name group should be spaced one line apart.

Comment: data.table is just habit, sorry for not including the library calls